# JQL - How to query for a list of epics and all its children issues when epics' due date = xxx?

Tags: jql

How to query for a list of epics and all its children issues when epics' due date is within a range and epics' due date is under a structure?
I have a query like this but it does not return children issues that do not have a due date or their due date is not within a range. I need all the issues as long as they are children of a list of epics where the epics meet certain criteria.

```
type not in (Milestone, Deliverable, Requirement)
AND due >= 2022-07-01
AND due <= 2022-09-30
AND issue in structure(2607, xxx-3546)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.